# how to select contents of table cell on tvOS

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos

I have a collectionView inside the table cells, but i can only click on the table cells.

Is there a way to disable user interaction on the table cells but enable it on the collectionCells inside the table cells, or a way to enter inside the table cells?

I show you an image below, where i cant click on the videos.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1qVF.jpg)

I am trying whit this and it works, but i cant scroll up the table view, i can only scroll down

```
public override var preferredFocusEnvironments: [UIFocusEnvironment] {
    return [collectionView]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding this code to my TableViewCell:

```
 public override var canBecomeFocused: Bool {
        return false
    }
```